# Plugin recommendation - posting to Social Networking sites

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I know there are a lot of Social Networking plugins around, so I thought I'd ask for some recommendations.

When writing a new post in the admin area (standard post type), I'd like the option to post it (the excerpt and a link, for instance) to my Facebook and Twitter accounts.

I'm not referring to buttons on the front-end for my users to share on their profiles.

Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this tutorial http://wpmu.org/automate-your-facebook-twitter-wordpress-post-updates-2-plugins/

a or if you feel like using an external serviceyou can use http://twitterfeed.com which is not a plugin but will do the job more then fine.

Comment: Looks good Bainternet, thanks. Isn't there a single plugin which does this though? I would've thought such a request would be fairly commonplace!